# How do tell JS that my api fetch link is NOT ok when it thinks it is?

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, error-handling

I'm having this issue with certain API's, where invalid links are still "ok". Here for the ticker symbol I typed a bunch of random letters in place of an actual ticker: ...`ticker=AAsdfsPL`... as opposed to ...`ticker=AAPL`... The API link itself still doesn't produce an error even though it doesn't really fetch any data. Any way to fix this or do I need to use a different API?

```
const resStock = await fetch(
      `https://api.polygon.io/v3/reference/tickers?ticker=AAsdfsPL&active=true&apiKey=key`
    );
    console.log(resStock.ok); //still returns true even though link doesn't do anything.
```

Comment: You probably want to flag the question and ask the moderators to remove your API key from it.

Comment: All the `ok` property tells you is that the **HTTP** operation completed with a success code. You then have to look to the API documentation to know whether you got anything back successfully. Your link above clearly returns valid JSON containing a `results` property with an empty array, so that's what you'd check.

Comment: [A `fetch()` promise will reject with a `TypeError` when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can check for the `count` property in the returned JSON to determine whether the result is valid or not:

```js
(async function () {
  const resStock = await fetch(
    `https://api.polygon.io/v3/reference/tickers?ticker=AAPsL&active=true&apiKey=6P2qV_oNdXnkkmnd5Vb5VtQWi09OIzfU`
  );
  let json;
  try {
    json = await resStock.json();
  } catch (e) {
    // Ignored
  }
  const isOk = json && !!json.count;
  console.log(isOk);
})();
```

Documentation: https://polygon.io/docs/stocks/get_v3_reference_tickers

Comment: Probably best to check `ok` before calling `resStock.json()` though, since if there's an HTTP error, calling `json()` will (almost certainly) result in a parsing error obscuring the actual problem that the HTTP request failed (in that case).

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder, good point! Modified my solution to add a try-catch instead to solve other potential issues as well

Comment: Why not...just check `ok` before calling `json()`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, maybe I am just being paranoid... at work I usually try to be safe it will always be a JSON, what if the server suddenly response `200` but is actually not a JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can distiguish the `result` whether it contains data or not

```
const resStock = await fetch(
   `https://api.polygon.io/v3/reference/tickers?ticker=AAsdfsPL&active=true&apiKey=6P2qV_oNdXnkkmnd5Vb5VtQWi09OIzfU`
)

if(resStock.results){
  //do the next steps
}
else {
   // you are not getting data, so throw error if you want to 
}
```

Comment: The [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object from `fetch` doesn't have a `data` property. You're probably thinking of axios.

Comment: `Response` doesn't have a `results` property either. You have to read the body of the response and parse it, as in the other answer.